# PowerShell System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException on Line 1 - Permissions?

Tags: 2010, permissions, powershell

I've adapted a PowerShell script from [Harry Chen's "SharePoint Connoisseur" blog](http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-upgrade-site-navigation.html) to solve the broken Navigation Up issue he describes. My code is slightly modified, but only to reduce the data captured and the sample size. Here's a code snippet:

```
$data = @()

Try
{
  $site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://theclients/site/collection"
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
  Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString()
}

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
  foreach($list in $web.Lists)
  {
    if($list.Title -eq "Pages")
    {
       DO STUFF
    }
  }
}
```

When I attempt to run the script (from SharePoint 2010 Management Shell as Administrator) I receive the following error:

```
C:\GetPagesInNeedOfUpdate.ps1 : Exception has been thrown by the target of an i
nvocation.
At line:1 char:30
+ C:\GetPagesInNeedOfUpdate.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [GetPagesInNeedOfUpdate.ps1],
  TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,GetP
  agesInNeedOfUpdate.ps1
```

Which is pretty ambiguous. Also, there is no character 30 at line 1...

Is this a permissions issue? The execution policy is set to `Unrestricted` so I know it isn't that, and my user has full control and is the primary site collection administrator.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got this script to work. I just checked the pages manually and manually removed the controls causing this... lame... if someone else has an answer I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the user account running the script to the Site Collections that you have and the error would go away.

As it turns out, it was permissions all along.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

your code is outside the try code block

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on why you think this is a problem. Thanks.

Comment: The first line runs successfully outside of the script. It's just initialization.